# Proof of $(ma+ nb, mn)=(a,n)(b,m)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b,m,n \in \mathbb Z$. If $(m,n)=1$ ( $m,n$ are coprime integers) prove that $(ma+ nb, mn)=(a,n)(b,m)$

I started the proof like this:

Let $c,d,e$ be the greatest common divisors of $(ma+nb,mn), (a,n), (b,m)$ respectively that is :

$c=x_{1}(ma+nb)+ y_{1}(mn)$,  $d=x_{2}a+ y_{2}n$,  $e=x_{3}b + y_{3}m$ for some $ x_{1}, y_{1}, x_{2}, y_{2}, x_{3}, y_{3}\in \mathbb Z$.

Then $$de=(x_{2}a+ y_{2}n)(x_{3}b + y_{3}m)=x_{2}x_{3}ab + x_{2}y_{3}am + y_{2}x_{3}nb + y_{2}y_{3}nm$$ but then I dont know what else to do. I can't use prime factorization in this proof.

I really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ By $\,(m,n)=1\,$ we have $\,(ma\!+\!nb,mn) = (ma\!+\!nb,m)\,(ma\!+\!nb,n),\ $ and

$\qquad\quad (ma\!+\!nb,m) = (nb,m) = (b,m),\ $ and $\ \ \ (ma\!+\!nb,n) = (ma,n) = (a,n)$

**Remark** $\ $ The inference in the first line is the special case $\,(m,n) = 1\ $ of this

**Lemma** $\ \ (k,m)(k,n) = (k,mn)\ \ $ if $\ \ \color{#c00}{(k,m,n) = 1}$

**Proof** $\quad\  (k,m)(k,n) = (k^2,km,kn,mn) = (k\color{#c00}{(k,m,n)},mn) = (k,mn)$

Comment: $(k,m,n)=1$ $\forall k\in \mathbb Z$ If $(m,n)=1$ ?

Comment: @user128422 Yes, $\,d\mid k,m,n\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid m,n\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid(m,n)=1.\, $ i.e. $\,(k,m,n)\mid (m,n).\ \ $

Comment: thanks a lot :) and one last question is the inverse also holds for $d=1$ ?

Comment: @user128422 No, $\,(k,m,n)=1\not\Rightarrow\,(m,n)=1,\,$ e.g. $\ (\,2\cdot 3,\,3\cdot 5,\, 5\cdot 2).$